# If you trigger Tree of Perdition's ability, then give the tree -13/-13, does the player go to 0 life?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you activate [Tree of Perdition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTree%20of%20Perdition%5d)'s ability, "Exchange target opponent's life total with Tree of Perdition's toughness", then play a spell before the ability resolves that brings the tree's toughness to 0, does the opponent's life total become 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - the Tree's ability will fail to do anything when it resolves. After the -13/-13 effect resolves, the Tree will die as a state-based action. Thus by the time the Tree's ability resolves, it won't be in play so the exchange can't happen.

The general rule:

> 701.8a A spell or ability may instruct players to exchange something (for example, life totals or control of two permanents) as part of its resolution. When such a spell or ability resolves, if the entire exchange can’t be completed, no part of the exchange occurs.

And confirming this, [a specific ruling for a very similar card](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247421):

> If Tree of Redemption isn’t on the battlefield when the ability resolves, the exchange can’t happen and the ability will have no effect.

Comment: In fact, if you look at the [Eldritch Moon release notes](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/eldritch-moon-release-notes-2016-07-08), you can see that Tree of Perdition itself has that specific ruling.